# Cat has wound above eye and on head

Tags: cats, health, feeding, diseases, eating

I am very worried because my British short hair cat has this wound at the eye and yesterday when I see it didn't have blood or anything, just the scalp. But when at night I checked, it had blood and got worse... and then, when I wanted to play with my favourtie cat Olie, I noticed her fur shedded around the head and saw a wound similar with my British short hair, but it looked like she didn't feel any pain, so I'm really worried.

I live in Singapore and I only give them food of Aatas Cat brand.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, I am sorry but I had to remove this formatting that was making the whole post displayed in bold because it was hard on the eyes to read, I also fixed some typos, please use "Side-by-side Markdown" option in revisions if you want to see what was modified with a clean view "before" and "after". I hope you get a good answer, the [cats] tag is the most active there so it should happen soon.

Comment: Are they indoor or outdoor cats? Do you have any other pets?

Comment: Please take them to a vet. We're mainly enthusiasts here, not professionals.

Answer (score 4):

Let's call the cat with the wound above the eye Cat A and the other one Cat B.

You'll need to get Cat A examined by a vet. This wound looks self-inflicted by scratching, which would also explain why it gets worse. The vet must find the reason why Cat A scratches itself. The reasons can range from fleas or mites over allergies to ear problems or an abscess, so it's impossible for us to diagnose your cat over the internet.

The wound on Cat B has a clear and sharp edge between fur and wound. It looks like she either hit her head somewhere or got into a fight. As long as the wound doesn't get worse or spreads, she doesn't need to go to the vet. If she didn't have a health checkup in more than a year, you can use this opportunity to get her checked anyway.

Keep in mind that if Cat A has any parasites like fleas, mites or worms, you **must treat both cats** against them, or the problem will jump from one cat to the other.